# AMQP 1.0 + RabbitMQ - Default Auto-Delete property not set for server named queue when receiver connects to exchange without queue address

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, amqp, auto-delete

I am working on a scenario where my receiver connects to RabbitMQ over AMQP 1.0 using protonJ2 library.

The address to connect contains exchange name but not the queue name. Queue address is kept empty.  WHat it does is, upon consumer connection, creates a server named queue and consumer connects to this queue.

Problem here is that this is not an *auto-delete* queue which is causing a number of unexpected maintenance chaos.

Our usecase is to have auto delete server named queues which gets deleted when no active consumer exists for this queue.

According to rabbitmq [github issue 2558](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/2588)

Please see below my code snippet

```
public void connectAmqp() throws Throwable {
final String serverHost = "localhost";
final int serverPort = 5672;
final String address = "/exchange/myTestExchange";
final Client client = Client.create();

try{
    ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions().user("user").password("pa$$w0rd");
    Connection connection = client.connect(serverHost, serverPort, options);
    /**
     * Consumer Connecting to Queue using exchange name
     */
    Receiver receiver = connection.openReceiver(address);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        Delivery delivery = receiver.receive();
        System.out.println(delivery.message().body().getClass());
        System.out.println("*-*-*-*          " + new String((byte[])delivery.message().body()));
    }
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    .....
}
}
```

[image: SrvrNamedQueue without autodelete]

**Workaround but not the solution**
I have done a work around to set 10 seconds EXPIRES policy on the queue name pattern "^amq.gen-*". But this is not the solution for the fact that it applies to all server named queues which I have no clue if might impact internal functionality of rabbitmq server.

```
rabbitmqctl set_policy servNamedQExpiry "^amq\.gen-*" '{"expires":10000}' --apply-to queues
```

Need help on how to set auto delete for Server Named Queues that get generated for queue-nameless consumer connections using exchange address.